# Using scala template code blocks and values as argument to template call (Play Framework)

Tags: scala, templates, playframework, playframework-2.0, twirl

I've tried to use both reusable code blocks and reusable values as argument to a function call (another template), but always end up in a compilation error: "illegal start of simple expression".

Let's say I have the `header` template, which takes a string as argument. It is called this way: `@header("My title")`

Now, I want "My title" to be the result of a code block, or a value.

For example, I have tried this way for a code block:

```
@headerText(workbookArea: WorkbookArea, workbookItemName: String) = @{
    workbookArea.className + " > " + workbookItemName
}

@header(@headerText(workbookArea, workbookItemName))
```

Or that way for a value:

```
@defining(workbookArea.className + " > " + workbookItemName) { headerText =>
    @header(@headerText)
}
```

But none of these two code snippets compile. How is it supposed to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be easier if you showed us an error, anyway - don't use the `@` symbol within the brackets, it should be:

```
@header(headerText(workbookArea, workbookItemName))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I realize that both work, when removing the "@" sign in `@headerText()` and `@headerText`. I shouldn't even have asked the question actually, it was a stupid mistake. What is best: delete the question, or accept your answer?

Comment: I think accept is ... acceptable, sometimes people does such mistakes, at least others will be able to find it. If I can suggest just add to your question also error produced by this case.